# Non-exponential time algorithm for subsequence using sum and product

Tags: algorithm, sequence, complexity-theory, target, exponential

Given a target number N and a sequence of M distinct numbers, using only sum and product operations , find the expression which is closest to the target. Each number from the sequence can be used only once. Does anyone know how can i solve  this in non-exponential time ?
Examples:
N = 5037
Sequence : 8 17 19 23 29 31 53
8*23*17 + 53*19 + 31 * 29 = 5034

N = 947
Sequence : 17 19 23 29
942=17*23+29*19

N = 3972
Sequence : 87 5 47
4089=87*47

Comment: How large are you expecting N and M to be?

Comment: It is not mentioned but i suppose they are not too big so you can declare a matrix of size N x M

Comment: You are asking how to solve at least NP-hard task in non-exponential time. Start by embracing the idea that it can't be solved, but can be optimized. Next course may provide you with some advanced techniques if your approaches won't work within your constraints: https://www.coursera.org/learn/discrete-optimization

Comment: "Each number from the sequence can be used only once." Exactly once or are you allowed to omit some numbers from the expression?

Comment: You can omit numbers from the expression , I will add an example to show this also , sorry :)

Comment: I don't see a non-exponential solution. I'd do a tree search, cutting off branches as soon as you see that they can't reach a better solution than the best one you already have. But that's still exponential-time.